# selenium WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH and

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

**WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.**
The message is occured while running a following code in anaconda **version 1.7.2**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c conda-forge geckodriver
```

The error can be removed by installing a geckodriver in conda environment