# Selenium and python : "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. "

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I was recently working with web automation, with Selenium and python, and  I faced into the error almost everyone got.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

window = webdriver.Firefox()
window.get("https://ecoledirecte.com")
```

But I looked up for several answers, and None of them worked ! I tried the solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335998/selenium-webdriverexception-message-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-pa) question, but nothing changed. I checked several times, and the geckodriver is in PATH (I extracted the file into my Downloads folder, then moved the executable into my main folder). I checked if indicating the mozilla geckovriver folder in the calling of `webdriver.Firefox()` would help (`webdriver.Firefox("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\mozilla-geckodriver-9b5f85c")`), but no.

Is there any reason for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I once put it in my System32 folder (which is in PATH!) but this is probably a little sketchy. Wherever you put the geckodriver, you just have to add that location to your PATH environment variable.

Try following this instruction:
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-install-geckodriver-Python-windows.php

I believe you could also install in the same folder where your python file is located - it should probably pick up that folder (but I'm not sure).

Comment: Thanks ! In fact, I added the geckodriver executable in PATH but not the geckodriver folder...

Answer (score 0):

this is an easy solution:

```
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='Your full path to the geckodriver executable'+'geckodriver')
```